# How to delete only (anyword).com in Regex?

Tags: r, regex, space

I'd like to match the following

```
My best email gmail.com
email com
email.com
```

to become

```
My best email
email com
*nothing*
```

Specifically, I'm using Regex for R, so I know there are different rules for escaping certain characters. I'm very new to Regex, but so far I have

```
\ .*(com)
```

which makes the same input

```
My
```

But this code does not work for instances where there are no spaces like the third example, and removes everything past the first space of a line if the line has a ".com"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following solution:

```
x <- c("My best email gmail.com","email com", "email.com", "smail.com text here")
trimws(gsub("\\S+\\.com\\b", "", x))
## => [1] "My best email" "email com"     ""              "text here"
```

See the R demo.

The `\\S+\\.com\\b` pattern matches 1+ non-whitespace chars followed by a literal `.com` followed by the word boundary.

The `trimws` function will trim all the resulting strings (as, e.g. with `"smail.com text here"`, when a space will remain after `smail.com` removal).

Note that TRE regex engine does not support shorthand character classes inside bracket expressions.